# eval() function not working with global scope

Tags: javascript, eval, createjs

I am using CreateJS to animate an object.

I want to move the `circle` shape to a position that changes in a for loop.

```
    var x = {
        time: 200,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
```

I am going to change this variable after every time the shape animates in a for loop.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        createjs.Tween.get(circle)
            .to({x: hits.x, y: hits.y}, hits.time);

    hits.x += 200;
    hits.y += 200;
    }
```

I have the increment value set to 4, but I am going to change it. This is why I am not directly using the `.to` function every time I am animating it. I do not want to hardcode every loop for every single increment. I need to make a single function that can take in any increment value and animate it accordingly.

I tried this out, but then realized that the animation doesn't take place if another animation is in progress.

I then used an eval function to add all the values to a string, and then doing it as a whole, as the `.to()` function is chainable.

```
     var bounceString = "createjs.Tween.get(circle)";
     for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        bounceString += ".to({x: hits.x, y: hits.y}, hits.time)";

    hits.x += 200;
    hits.y += 200;
    }
    bounceString += ";";
    eval(bounceString);
```

By using the eval function with the string, I can use any increment value and animate the shape accordingly without having to hardcode it. However, there is a problem.

I have no clue why, but it says that the `hits` variable is undefined. I also tried to define that variable in the `bounceString`, but it did not work out. I also tried making it a global variable (as the whole code is in a function).

The error that shows up when I try to define `hits` in `bounceString` is this-

[image: Error]

This happens only when I am trying to define the variable in the string itself.

I know that the `eval` function is dangerous, but this is the only way. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Just chain without `eval` (save the chainable object in a variable). There's absolutely no reason to use it here, and you won't get problems either.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry- Read my comment on the first answer. I have made the changes.

Comment: A simple loop doesn't hardcode anything. It can take the number of iterations as an arguments just as well. `eval` does not make any sense here. Clear your mind from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the API for `createjs` is.  However, I would expect that storing what you get from `createjs.Tween.get()` and then doing the `.to()` would be **far** better than anything `eval()` does for you.

Consider the following code:

```
// Store the tween
var c = createjs.Tween.get(circle);

// Create your keyframes
var keyframes = [],
    keyframe;

for (keyframe = 0; keyframe < 4; keyframe += 1) {
    keyframes.push({
        x: 200 * keyframe,
        y: 200 * keyframe
    });
}

// Do your iterations on tween
keyframes.reduce(function (prev, curr, i, arr) {
    return prev.to({
        x: arr[i].x,
        y: arr[i].y
    });
}, c.to({
    x: keyframes[0].x,
    y: keyframes[0].y
}));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a `for` loop *and* `reduce`, should you?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate the reduction. Your array already contains exactly the arguments, so go for `keyframes.reduce(function(chain, cur) { return chain.to(cur); }, createjs.Tween.get(circle));`

Comment: Sorry I haven't mentioned this, but I am going to change the values. In my example given above, I have 4 as the increment, and I need to do it 4 times. However, I am going to be using many different increments, and I don't want to hardcode it for each of them. This is why I need to have the eval function to run the whole thing.

Comment: @Ron He has the number 4 in the above code once. You can move this code to a function and provide `4/112/42/whatevs` as an argument. eval is **almost never** necessary. Exceptions include checking ES6 syntax support, and letting a JavaScript developer test his code.